Standard deviation tells how a data is spread around mean. Then what is 1 SD (68%), 2SD (95%)?
I am learning statistics from scratch. I understand that SD would tell how datapoints are spread around mean. However, I do not understand how it is useful in finding outliers. Especially, these two images 68-95-99 image and S.D. image are confusing.
A nice visual representation that combines these two would be helpful.
Also, how can I know that my temperature dataset with 10 entries is normally distributed? Isn't temperature always normally distributed? I read somewhere that I can't do any statistical tests on this dataset, why?

Are you talking about multiple measurements of a presumably common underlying value, so we're interested in the distribution of measurement errors? if so, see here for why they're often Normal.

Statistical tests are the most commonly used methods to check the normality of a data distribution. The most common tests are:
Kolmogorov-Smirnov test: Compares the empirical distribution with a normal distribution. If the test result is statistically significant $(p =0.05)$, it means that the distribution of the variable differs from the normal distribution. However, it is sensitive to large samples, which can lead to false rejection of normality in larger data sets.
Shapiro-Wilk test: Is more accurate for small samples. The result of the Shapiro-Wilk test indicates whether the deviation from normality is statistically significant. A significant result $(p = 0.05)$ suggests that the distribution of a variable differs from normal.
